# AWS Forecast error saying filter id is missing or invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

Whenever I want to do a Forecast lookup I get the following error message:

```
Bad request
ResourceNotFoundException : The query did not return any forecast results as the required filter id is either missing or is invalid.
```

I'm clueless about why I get this error. I checked my Forecast key (which is item_id) and value (which is F11) and they fit with the .csv I used for my dataset. I also checked for the order of my attributes that I set for my dataset and they also fit with my .csv.

An example line in my csv looks like this:

```
2016-12-07, 2, LAE, F11, 190, 190, 215, 58, 58, 79, 0, 23, ****
```

And my data schema looks like this:

```
{
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "timestamp",
            "AttributeType": "timestamp"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "location",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "mpkt",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "item_id",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "PL_atag",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "SO_atag",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "demand",
            "AttributeType": "float"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "plumlauf",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "sumlauf",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "umlauf",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "diff_mpp",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "diff_rp",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "fst_fber",
            "AttributeType": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

So where is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to provide any item_id value of forecast key which is present in your dataset. In aws-forecast we can see the details of any one item at a time. Different item will have different forecast result.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by input include blank.
In your case, you should input " F11" for item_id.